# Graphically view long line diffs that mostly match

Tags: diff, viewer

I have two data files. They're both 5000 lines long, and each row is ~10000 characters wide. They are nearly identical, except a few characters on some lines are different. Is there any tool that will jump both **vertically** and **horizontally** to the disagreements for both sides, so I can see what's different?

I'm using OSX, but I could use Linux or windows if it was absolutely necessary. I've tried:

- FileMerge
- KDiff3
- DiffMerge
- command line diff
- Now trying to install meld

Answer (score 0):

vimdiff, or even better its graphical twin gvimdiff, would work if there is at most two edits per line.  It highlights the part between the first and last changed character on a line.  It also collapses the parts of the files which are identical.

These are part of [Vim](http://www.vim.org/); I have no idea whether the [MacOS versions](http://www.vim.org/download.php#mac) contain (g)vimdiff.

Note that in my experience Vim sometimes becomes slow with long lines, so that might hurt you for this specific use case.

Answer (score 0):

[Araxis Merge](http://www.araxis.com/merge_mac/index.html) may do what you're after (it does character-diffs within lines), and there's an OSX version. It's not cheap, and I've never tried it on 10,000 character wide lines, though.